# C: String Concatenation via Pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I am learning C.. coming from a C# background I find most of it very easy to transition over to.. pointers however are proving quite troublesome.. I have created a small test app (see below) for concatenating 2 strings via pointers. I am getting this error:

```
error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
```

How do I fix this?

```
void concatTest();

int main()
{
    concatTest();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void concatTest()
{
    char string1[20], string2[20], string3[40];
    char *ptr1, *ptr2, *ptr3;
    ptr1 = &string1[0];
    ptr2 = &string2[0];
    ptr3 = &string3[0];
    int i;

    printf("You need to enter 2 strings.. each of which is no more than 20 chars in length: \n");

    printf("Enter string #1: \n");
    scanf("%s", string1);

    printf("Enter string #2: \n");
    scanf("%s", string2);

    int len1 = strlen(string1);
    int len2 = strlen(string2);

    for (i = 0; i < len1; i++)
    {
        *ptr3[i] = *ptr1[i];
    }
    for (i = len1; i < len1 + len2; i++)
    {
        *ptr3[i] = *ptr2[i];
    }
    //TODO: show concatenated string on console
}
```

Comment: You should use `scanf("%20s", string1)` here.

Comment: Your second loop is incorrect, you need to start copying from the beginning of the second string (but still append to the end of the final string of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ptr1[i]` has already dereferenced the array.  There is no need to use `*` as well.

[*However, even if you fix that, your code is still broken; you haven't taken null-terminators into account.*]

Comment: Thank you Oli for such a quick and concise answer. I have another one about the null terminated strings here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496624/c-string-concatentation-null-terminated-strings

Answer (score -2):

```
the name of array as a point
ptr1  = string1; ptr1 point at the array string1,so ptr1[i] is just like string1[i]

ptr1  = string1;
ptr2  = string2;
ptr3  = string3;
```

Comment: Adding some text might help us to understand what you want to say!!

Comment: very poor comment, be mor specific and clear with your comment