# C: String Concatentation: Null Terminated Strings

Tags: c, pointers, null-terminated

The following code only concatenates the first string and ignores the second.. from what I gather, it has something to do with Null terminated strings. As I am new to C, this is a new concept to me. Could someone help make the code below work? That would really help me a lot in understanding this.

```
void concatTest();

int main()
{
    concatTest();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void concatTest()
{
    char string1[20], string2[20], string3[40];
    char *ptr1, *ptr2, *ptr3;
    ptr1 = &string1[0];
    ptr2 = &string2[0];
    ptr3 = &string3[0];
    int i;

    printf("You need to enter 2 strings.. each of which is no more than 20 chars in length: \n");

    printf("Enter string #1: \n");
    scanf("%s", string1);

    printf("Enter string #2: \n");
    scanf("%s", string2);

    int len1 = strlen(string1);
    int len2 = strlen(string2);

    for (i = 0; i < len1; i++)
    {
        ptr3[i] = ptr1[i];
    }
    for (i = len1; i < len1 + len2; i++)
    {
        ptr3[i] = ptr2[i];
    }

    printf("%s\n", string3);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indexing `ptr2[i]` using `i` which ranges from `len1` to `len1 + len2`. This value will probably be out of bounds of the `string2` array (unless the first string you type happens to be empty).

I might write your second loop as follows:

```
for (i = 0; i < len2; i++) {
    ptr3[len1 + i] = ptr2[i];
}
```

Comment: Excellent. thank you Greg.. I'll accept your answer as soon as StackOverflow lets me (about another 7 minutes)..

Comment: I kinda liked having the index start at the point in ptr3 like in the original code -- thought it was clearer.  Just have to copy from the right location.

Answer (score 2):

My answer will have no code, but hopefully a useful explanation.

Each string in C is terminated with `\0`.

If you want to concatenate two strings you need to be sure you *overwrite the last character* of the first string (the `\0`) with the *first* character of the 2nd string. Otherwise, no matter how long the "concatenated" string is, as soon as a `\0` is encountered by a string function, it will assume the end of the string has reached.

And of course you need to be sure you have enough allocated space for the joint string.

Comment: I guessed that, thanks. But, what I need is a code example.. how to actually do that? I'll probably kick myself when I get the answer.. but right now I just can't see it

Comment: Thanks again. Not the answer I was looking for, but you get an up vote anyway  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to start at the first character of ptr2.

```
ptr3[i] = ptr2[i-len1];
```

> from what I gather, it has something to do with Null terminated
>   strings.

Yes it does.  Strings start at offset 0.  You were starting at some random point based on the length of the fist string.